# Javascript mouseout strange behaviour

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am customizing a [jquery ui datepicker](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/) to display when focusing on the associated input field, and hide when the mouse cursor leaves the whole div containing both the input field and datepicker (`fromSelector`/`toSelector`).
The problem I have is with the mouseout event, which triggers when the cursor leaves the `#to` or `#from` inputfield instead of when I leave the whole div

In my html and js files I have:

*index.html.erb*

```
   <div class="six columns" id = "fromSelector">
      From
      <%= text_field_tag :from, @from.strftime('%d/%m/%Y') %>
      <div id="fromDiv"></div>
   </div>

   <div class="six columns end" id = "toSelector">
      To
      <%= text_field_tag :to, @to.strftime('%d/%m/%Y') %>
      <div id="toDiv"></div>
   </div>

   <div class="twelve columns end">
      <%= submit_tag 'Calculate', :class => 'secondary button', :id => 'submitDate' %>
   </div>
```

*chart_initialize.js*

```
initializeDatepicker: function () {

$( "#fromDiv" ).datepicker({
  yearRange: "-5:+0",
  altFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
  altField: '#from',
  changeMonth: true,
  changeYear: true
});
$( "#toDiv" ).datepicker({
  yearRange: '-5:+0',
  altFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
  altField: '#to',
  changeMonth: true,
  changeYear: true
});

$('#from').on('focus', function () {
  $('#fromDiv').slideDown(300);
});
$('#fromSelector').on('mouseout', function () {
  $('#fromDiv').slideUp(300);
});

$('#to').on('focus', function () {
  $('#toDiv').slideDown(300);
});
$('#toSelector').on('mouseout', function () {
  alert("test");
  $('#toDiv').slideUp(300);
});


},
```

(The rails `text_field_tag` helpers create inputs with name and id of 'from' / 'to')

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Did you try using mouseleave instead

Comment: use mouseleave, mouseout behaves different when the element has children. Details here http://www.mkyong.com/jquery/different-between-mouseout-and-mouseleave-in-jquery/